# tableView cells wont change font color

Tags: iphone, uitableview, fonts, ios4

I have done many approach on changing font colors from a tableView cell. apparently both method failed. Unless I am doing it wrongly, then I need some help to correct it. Here is the code I found online to change the font color.

```
[[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:76.0/255.0 blue:76.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
```

I placed that line in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and it did not work. Next, I searched this page and found another method to change font colors: `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` I copied and paste the setTextColor method into the `willDisplayCell` method and it did not work either. Below is the source code on which how I attempted and failed:

#### cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ApplicationCell";

    ApplicationCell *cell = (ApplicationCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PharmacyCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tempCell;
        self.tempCell = nil;
    }

    //cell.useDarkBackground = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0);
    HealthWellness *objHealth = [self.maHealthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.strPharmacyName = [objHealth.healthName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@""];
    [[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:76.0/255.0 blue:76.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

#### tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:76.0/255.0 blue:76.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
}
```

#### ApplicationCell.h

```
@interface ApplicationCell : UITableViewCell{
//variable declaration
BOOL useDarkBackground;
BOOL useMenuBackground;
NSString *strPharmacyName;
UIImage *pharmacyIcon;
NSString *strStoreName;}
```

//setting property
@property BOOL useDarkBackground;
@property BOOL useMenuBackground;
@property(retain) NSString *strPharmacyName;
@property(retain) UIImage *pharmacyIcon;
@property(retain) NSString *strStoreName;

#### ApplicationCell.m

```
- (void)setUseDarkBackground:(BOOL)flag{
if (flag != useDarkBackground || !self.backgroundView)
{
    useDarkBackground = flag;

    NSString *backgroundImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:useDarkBackground ? @"BGDark" : @"BGLight" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:backgroundImagePath] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:1.0];
    self.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage] autorelease];
    self.backgroundView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.backgroundView.frame = self.bounds;
}}



- (void)setUseMenuBackground:(BOOL)flag{
if (flag != useDarkBackground || !self.backgroundView)
{
    useDarkBackground = flag;
    NSString *backgroundImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:useDarkBackground ? @"BGDark" : @"BGLight" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:backgroundImagePath] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:1.0];
    self.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage] autorelease];
    self.backgroundView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.backgroundView.frame = self.bounds;

}}
```

Comment: Where you are creating the **tempCell**?

Comment: Can you post the interface of `ApplicationCell`?

Comment: its a custom cell that has been created. Sorry this project is a pass down, so I am not the rightful owner of the codes.

Comment: the `ApplicationCell` codes are hellish long, want me to 'answer my own question? or just continue to edit for the question?

Comment: most interesting method to change color in cell is using `UILabel`.

Comment: why do you say that sherilyn? I did get this online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` and since you mention that there is a lot going on in the `ApplicationCell` class. I am guessing that your subclass isn't making use of the `textLabel` field since your changes aren't reflecting on the UI.

Check for the property outlet that is being displayed on screen from your `ApplicationCell` interface declaration & the `NIB` file. Once you've the appropriate property outlet, change its property.

Comment: Thanks Deepak for your quick response. I will try them out later. Now my boss wants something else from me :(

Comment: ok, I have edited the question. I have the ApplicationCell inserted

Comment: @Melvin Lai is there any mention of `UILabel` or `textlabel` in your `ApplicationCell` code?

Answer (score 0):

That should set the text color, I just tried it and it works.  cell should be a UITableView though, does your ApplicationCell inherit from UITableView cell?
Also if ApplicationCell is nil, I'm not sure whats going on with tempCell

try

> cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

and go from there